# Umbrella header for module 'DJIUXSDK' does not include header 'DUXManualZoomBaseWidget.h'

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

When importing `DJIUXSDK` 4.8 as a framework, and not using cocoapods, after cleaning our project, we're seeing this error when trying to build:

`Umbrella header for module 'DJIUXSDK' does not include header 'DUXManualZoomBaseWidget.h'`

Comment: I've never used this SDK, but this seems something related to the imports on the bridging header. I think the umbrella header of this `DJIUXSDK` is missing the header import of `DUXManualZoomBaseWidget`.

Comment: @Bryan what version of Xcode are you using to compile? I'm able to get a sample app using UXSDK 4.8 without cocoa pods to compile in 10.1.

Comment: Xcode 10.1. I can get it to compile too, but a clean followed by a build always produces that error. Rebuilding thereafter (without cleaning) does succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `DUXManualZoomBaseWidget.h` is a public header and is not included in umbrella header of the framework. 
This kind of error occurs when a compiler flag `-Wincomplete-umbrella` is on.
So I would look in your project build settings for this flag and if it's on, just turn it off, it should work.

Comment: Setting that compiler flag in this case just quiets the originating problem, it doesn't actually solve the missing header issue.

Comment: That is true, but to solve this issue completely you would need access to the framework you're using.You can either add `DUXManualZoomBaseWidget.h` to umbrella header or change its visibility scope, making it not `public`, but `private` or `project`.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this, it looks like DUXManualZoomBaseWidget.h header was released too soon and is not yet supported - good catch.  At this point, please use the UXSDK without this feature until further notice.